# ACF Repeater field returns string containing the count of repeater

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, repeater, acfpro

When I use `get_field('repeater_name')` it returns a string that contains the a number which is the count of the repeater while it should return array of sub-fields, this issue have been reported repeatedly before but none of them provided a stable fix to this, the only way is to edit the post and hit the update button and it will re-generate the repeater fields, but in my case, I have 19k posts and it's not possible to edit each post.

Also `have_rows('repeater_name')` returns false as expected and the real field data (`get_post_meta($post_id, "field_{$field_key}", true)` returns `NULL`

I would appreciate any help or any automated script that regenerates the repeater field keys and populate the values of all posts.

This issue is reported previously in [here](https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/repeater-field-returns-string/), [here](https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/get_field-for-repeater-returning-string-instead-of-array/) and [here](https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/repeater-field-is-returning-a-string-not-array/) and none came with a real fix.

**EDIT:** 
I spotted the problem, the problem is in `wp_postmeta` table, the wrong field keys are stored:

`wp_postmeta table`

```
| meta_key                | meta_value    | 
| -------------           |:-------------:|
| _repeater_name          | field_XXXXXXX |
| _repeater_0_subfield    | field_ABCDEFG |
| _repeater_0_subfield2   | field_HIJKLMN |
```

The same field keys should match in `wp_posts` table, but they don't (maybe due to data migration or whatever reason):

```
| post_excerpt   | post_name     | post_type | 
| ---------------| ------------- |-----------|
| repeater_name  | field_YYYYYYY | acf-field |
| subfield       | field_BBBBBBB | acf-field |
| subfield2      | field_CCCCCCC | acf-field |
```

I think if there's a way to sync field keys in the database, that will fix the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made a solution for this, might not be the exact solution for this problem but it worked out for me, I wrote this fix to rebuild faulty fields, it will rebuild only fields that have this problem:

```
/**
 * @param string $name
 * @param string[] $keys
 * @param int|null|\WP_Post $post
 */
function dw_build_repeater($name, $keys = [], $post = null) {
    $post = get_post($post);
    $repeater = get_field($name, $post->ID);
    $arr = [];

    if (is_array($repeater)) {
        return $repeater;
    }

    if (!$repeater || !is_numeric($repeater)) {
        return $arr;
    }

    for ($i = 0; $i < intval($repeater); $i++) {
        foreach ($keys as $key) {
            $arr[$i][$key] = get_post_meta($post->ID, $name . "_" . $i . "_{$key}");
        }
    }

    update_field($name, $arr, $post->ID);

    return $arr;
}
```

so whenever i want to call a repeater i simply do this:

```
if (
    have_rows('repeater_name')
    || dw_build_repeater('repeater_name', ['subfield1', 'subfield2', 'subfield3'])
) {
     while (have_rows('repeater_name')) {
          the_row();
          // And the rest
     }

}

// OR simply with a foreach loop
foereach (dw_build_repeater('repeater_name', ['subfield1', 'subfield2', 'subfield3']) as $row) {
    echo $row['subfield1'] ?? '';
}
```

I haven't tested it with nested repeaters but i suppose it might not be working with nested repeaters.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having this issue when trying to access repeaters added to options pages through the PHP API. Specifically, in my case I was trying to get the repeater data during the `acf/load_field` filter. It didn't matter whether the hook was registered during `init` or `acf_init`.

I discovered that, at least in this case, you always have to call `acf_enable_filter( 'local' )` before `get_field()` to get the data array instead of the item count.